# Chance on generating 2 equal hashes based on time()?

Tags: hash

Question is pretty simple, but I couldn't find an answer for this one... Basicly, my application is generating filenames with `md5(time());`.

What are the chances, if any, that using this technique, I'll have 2 equal results?

P.S. Since my question title says hashes not exact hash, what are the chances, if any, again, of generating equal results for each type of hashes `sha1();`, `sha512();` etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the chances that someone will change the system time?

Comment: @khachik: NTP might do that, if you're using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Equal* results are unlikely to result from this, you can simply validate that yourself by checking the uniqueness of `md5(0)` ... `md5(INT32_MAX)` since that's the total range of a `time_t`. I don't think there are collisions in that input space for any of the hashes you've named.

*Predictable* results is another matter, though. By choosing `time()` as you input supplier, you restrict yourself to, well, one unique hash per second, no more than 86400 per day, ...

Answer (score 1):

My estimation is it is unsafe due to possible changes in time by humans and other processes such as NTP which FrankH has kindly noted.  I highly recommend using a cryptographically secure RNG (random number generator) if your framework allows.

Comment: Interesting answer, but what you describe as cryptographically secure RNG?

Comment: Wikipedia has a good article on this topic:  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

.NET provides such an RNG in RNGCryptoServiceProvider